# Partition csv source in Azure Synapse copy activity

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

Maybe a stupid question, but I spent hours searching for any info and could not find anything...

Does activating Partition - Dynamic range option bring anything for the copy activity when reading from a *.csv file from blob storage using serverless pool' view?

My csv file contains 10 Mio rows

Comment: except for sql source, partitions are done automatically on source based upon the size of data. While using partition for sinks yield quicker writes. See surrounding MS docs [Optimizing sources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-performance-sources) & [Optimizing sinks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-performance-sinks)

Comment: Thanks @KarthikBhyresh-MT The info you have linked is however regarding mapping data flows, not copy activity in pipelines. Or it does not really matter?

Comment: Activating Dynamic Partitioning on the ID column of the source, helped to save 2 min (ca 45%) of the pipeline execution time.